# Rooms between asker & answerer are being deleted, despite holding the answer

Tags: discussion, chat

When I created a chat room for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329100/changing-base-url-to-allow-relative-links/16329141#16329141), I helped the user solve all of their problems there.

If another user were to come to the question and have the same problems, they'd click the chat link, right? Guess what? It's gone.

Why are we deleting answer-asker chatrooms?

Comment: You probably didn't expand the comments?

Comment: @Mysticial I helped solve his problems in that chat room.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same confusion as I did the room is still there at present but the final message is `
This room has been automatically deleted for inactivity`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chat is not the place where you should be keeping solutions to problems. Chat rooms are not expected to stay around forever, so once you solve a problem in a chat room, you should write it up as an answer to the question, or write up a new question if the problem is different from the original one.

Comment: All good and well, but the system should tidy up its own "dead" (for all intents and purposes) links then.

Comment: Well, if the initial answer didn't work, and it's continued in comments, then in chat, why don't we just keep the chatroom instead of  making the answerer update the question? I know, it sounds silly, but if there already is a link to the info, why delete it?

Comment: Comments are also supposed to be transient. I agree that it would be good for the system to delete dead links to deleted chat rooms, but the main problem here is still that the answer isn't *in an answer*.

Comment: @IanCarroll Putting an answer behind a link in a comment is worse than having a link-only answer because comments should be expected to be deleted at any time.

Comment: @Ian if new information was raised in chat and it helped solve the problem, why doesn't that new information get added to an answer, rather than leave it in either of two places that are likely to disappear?

Comment: Also, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to *quickly* find answers to questions. If the answers are buried in a chat, then we're not much better than the forums, where the answer is on page 8 of 21 1/3 of the way down the page.